# Sudden drop in SQL Azure query performance after moving web app to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, sql-tuning, sql-query-store

What could explain this big drop in performance in an Azure SQL DB after moving the app from an hosted VPS to an Azure App service?

[image]

Here's a typical chart from Query Store's High Variation chart over the past two weeks. The red arrow indicates when I moved the production app from another hosting provider to an Azure App. Prior to moving the app, I experienced zero timeouts. Now, using the same Azure SQL DB, timeouts are triggering frequently for longish queries (but by no means too arduous).

The only other change I made was change the user principle in the connection string. This user only has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and EXECUTE permissions.

My theories are:
 - something to do with networking between the app and the db. Resiliency? But I have a SQL exec plan specified
 - something wrong with the user I set up?
 - bad plan regression (I have now enabled auto FORCE PLAN tuning)
 - a problem caused by Hangfire running on two servers simultaneously (now mitigated by moving HF tables to a new DB)
 - something is triggering some kind of throttling that I cannot figure out.

Here is a chart of timeouts from Log Analytics:

[image]

All help appreciated. Note: this site has had almost identical traffic over the past 30 days.

In fact, take a look at this from the SQL DB metrics over the past week:

[image]

And here is some Wait info - last 6 hours:

Blue = PARALLELISM
Orange = BUFFERIO

[image]

Comment: You moved the web app to Azure but the DB didn't change, right?

Comment: Exactly right. I also changed the db user in the connection string.

Comment: I'm now wondering if the middle chart from Log Analytics is misleading as I'm not sure when logging began for that service. For the most part, the site is super fast - just every now and then a long running query seems to bring it down completely.

Comment: Same DB and same application should have no impact in DB performance in my opinion. Can you undo the connection string change just to rule out a possibility?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the user in the connection string right now. Everything else in the string is identical. The reason I ask is because I saw an answer on SO (although not fully answered, and I can't find it now) that suggested the db user needs access to the Master db, not just your target db.

Comment: Can you try updating stats and indexes ,also which metric is  over 90% for long periods of time(cpu,io,ram,log)